# Integrate gmail in android app like facebook

Tags: android, facebook, gmail

I want to integrate gmail in my android app just like we do for facebook.
I used the sample provided by "sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/samples/auth" but this is not exactly i wanted. Please give your valuable suggestion. Thanks

Comment: `javamail.jar` is easy to use: http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Comment: @alfasin: You misunderstood my question, I want to authenticate user using gmail in dialog just like facebook authenticate user in android app.Do you have any idea regarding this? please help

Comment: have a look at [how-to-login-with-gmail-in-android](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/google-account-integration-in-android-login-with-gmail.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use xmpp for integrating gmail into your app. It is easy to use. you can download asmack.jar for this.